# Generating unique event ID based on consecutive dated element and time type in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

Hope you guys are doing well.Thank you so much in advance.Your help will really appreciated.

Got into trouble to create the XSLT (v2.0) for below requirement.Not getting how to achieve it.

**Requirement:** 
Generate a unique **Event Id**  based on consultative date and time type for each employees.

**Example:** For employee **EMP12345** is on Annual leave for date 2015-03-31, Sick leave for period 2015-04-01 to 2015-04-03 and 2015-04-15 to 2015-04-16.

So there are 2 consecutive dated sick  leave .So need to generate the two unique event id.

Please refer the below expected output.

**XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Data>
<Employee>
    <Employee_ID>EMP12345</Employee_ID>
    <Time_type>Annual</Time_type>
    <Date>2015-03-31</Date>
    <Hours>6</Hours>
</Employee>
<Employee>
    <Employee_ID>EMP12345</Employee_ID>
    <Time_type>Sick</Time_type>
    <Date>2015-04-01</Date>
    <Hours>6</Hours>
</Employee>
<Employee>
    <Employee_ID>EMP12345</Employee_ID>
    <Time_type>Sick</Time_type>
    <Date>2015-04-02</Date>
    <Hours>6</Hours>
</Employee>
<Employee>
    <Employee_ID>EMP12345</Employee_ID>
    <Time_type>Sick</Time_type>
    <Date>2015-04-03</Date>
    <Hours>6</Hours>
</Employee>
<Employee>
    <Employee_ID>EMP12345</Employee_ID>
    <Time_type>Sick</Time_type>
    <Date>2015-04-15</Date>
    <Hours>6</Hours>
</Employee>
<Employee>
    <Employee_ID>EMP12345</Employee_ID>
    <Time_type>Sick</Time_type>
    <Date>2015-04-16</Date>
    <Hours>6</Hours>
</Employee>
<Employee>
    <Employee_ID>EMP12346</Employee_ID>
    <Time_type>Sick</Time_type>
    <Date>2015-04-01</Date>
    <Hours>6</Hours>
</Employee>
<Employee>
    <Employee_ID>EMP12346</Employee_ID>
    <Time_type>Sick</Time_type>
    <Date>2015-04-02</Date>
    <Hours>6</Hours>
</Employee>
</Data>
```

**Expected output:**

```
Employee ID,Time Type,Date,Hours,Event ID
EMP12345,Annual,2015-03-31,6,
EMP12345,Sick,2015-04-01,6,12344EMP12345
EMP12345,Sick,2015-04-02,6,12344EMP12345
EMP12345,Sick,2015-04-03,6,12344EMP12345
EMP12345,Sick,2015-04-15,6,22344EMP12345
EMP12345,Sick,2015-04-16,6,22344EMP12345
EMP12346,Sick,2015-04-01,6,11111EMP12346
EMP12346,Sick,2015-04-02,6,11111EMP12346
```

Thanks,

Deepak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to do this, is to use `xsl:for-each-group`, and group starting by the `Employee` elements where the date is not one day after the previous one (i.e they are the start of a new group)

```
  <xsl:for-each-group select="Employee" group-starting-with="Employee[not(
       Employee_ID = preceding-sibling::Employee[1]/Employee_ID 
       and Time_type = preceding-sibling::Employee[1]/Time_type 
       and xs:date(Date) = xs:date(preceding-sibling::Employee[1]/Date) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'))]">
```

I am sure if you have a specific rule for generating the EventId, but one possible way would be as follows

```
<xsl:variable name="EventId" select="concat(Employee_ID, '-', position())" />
```

You would then use `current-group()` to output all the rows in that particular group, with the same EventId. Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="Data">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Employee" group-starting-with="Employee[not(
        Employee_ID = preceding-sibling::Employee[1]/Employee_ID 
        and Time_type = preceding-sibling::Employee[1]/Time_type 
        and xs:date(Date) = xs:date(preceding-sibling::Employee[1]/Date) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'))]">
          <xsl:variable name="EventId" select="concat(Employee_ID, '-', position())" />
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
              <xsl:value-of select="Employee_ID" />
              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="Time_type" />
              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="Date" />
              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="Hours" />
              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="$EventId" />
              <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to you current XML, the following is output

```
EMP12345,Annual,2015-03-31,6,EMP12345-1
EMP12345,Sick,2015-04-01,6,EMP12345-2
EMP12345,Sick,2015-04-02,6,EMP12345-2
EMP12345,Sick,2015-04-03,6,EMP12345-2
EMP12345,Sick,2015-04-15,6,EMP12345-3
EMP12345,Sick,2015-04-16,6,EMP12345-3
EMP12346,Sick,2015-04-01,6,EMP12346-4
EMP12346,Sick,2015-04-02,6,EMP12346-4
```

Note, this does assume the `Employee` elements are sorted in `Employee_id`, `Date`, and `time_type` order.

Comment: Thanks tim,I will try out. Assume that if the employees taken sick leaves starting from Friday to Tuesday.  Leave is consecutive but date will not come consecutive like 2015-04-17,2015-04-17.For this example date will come 2015-04-17,2015-04-20,2015-04-21. Because Saturday n Sunday will not get counted. Is this possible to incorporate this logic in above xslt. If date difference is there should be two days difference and first date should be Friday n next date should be Monday this should also have unique event id.Thank you Tim.

Comment: Thank i have modified the xslt. able to apply the logic for above requirement.

Answer (score 0):

A big Thanks to @Tim for providing me the solution.
I have just added the few criteria to full fill the requirement.

Below is the updated XSLT.

```html
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="Data">
   <xsl:for-each-group select="Employee" group-starting-with="Employee[not(
        Employee_ID = preceding-sibling::Employee[1]/Employee_ID 
        and Time_type = preceding-sibling::Employee[1]/Time_type 
        and ((xs:date(Date) =  xs:date(preceding-sibling::Employee[1]/Date) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')) 
  or ((xs:date(Date) =  xs:date(preceding-sibling::Employee[1]/Date) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P3D')) and (format-date(xs:date(Date),'[F]')='Monday') and (format-date((xs:date(preceding-sibling::Employee[1]/Date)),'[F]')='Friday')  ) ))]">
          <xsl:variable name="EventId" select="concat(Employee_ID, '-', position())" />
  <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
              <xsl:value-of select="Employee_ID" />
              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="Time_type" />
              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="Date" />
              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="Hours" />
              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="$EventId" />
              
              <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```